# Change Reference

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am still working on streamlining our Attendance worksheet and I decided to add a macro for copying the last three rows and pasting them at the end; the only problem is I need the formula in the first two cells to only change their cell references by 1. The code I have so far is

```
Sub New_Weekly_Row()

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Resize(3).EntireRow.Copy
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(3).EntireRow.PasteSpecial
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Resize(2, 1).Select
    
    
End Sub
```

I have been trying to see if there is a way to either lock the references (both cells that would be copied would just be something like =U34 and =W34 respectively) to only increasing by one or subtracting two from the cells that are pasted to.

The closest thing I have found so far is

```
Dim r As Range, b As Integer

    Set r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2)

    b = Val(Right(r.Formula, Len(r.Formula) - 3))

    b = b - 2

r.Formula = Range("U" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp) + CStr(b)
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Select
```

But that just enters it as plain text.

This worked a few times, but stopped

```
Sub Update_Reference()

     Dim myCell  As Range

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Resize(2).Select
    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.HasFormula Then myCell.Formula = Left(myCell.Formula, _
                                                Len(myCell.Formula) - 1) & 4
    Next myCell
 
End Sub
```

I don't know if this information helps any, but this will be used in conjunction with this

```
Sub New_Weekly_Row()

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Resize(3).EntireRow.Copy
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(3).EntireRow.PasteSpecial
    Range("U" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Merge (Across)
    Range("W" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Merge (Across)
    Range("Y" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Merge (Across)
    Range("AA" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Merge (Across)
    Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 8).Copy
    Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 8).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
    

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify a little more A81 has the string =U33 and A82 has the string =W33; when they are copied to A84 and A85, respectively, I just want them to change to =U34 and =W34 respectively
Edit: brackets removed

Comment: Try using R1C1 cell references in the formula.

Comment: If you are just adding rows then I recommend making the dataset in to a table object. Select the data and hit `CTRL+T` to define a table. Then you can add rows with `tbl.ListRows.Add`

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't see how R1C1 would affect this, wouldn't the reference still be updating by 3 instead of 1? As for setting it as a table, I need to keep a base format for our timekeeper. I am just streamlining this to make attendance easier for our other Leads.

Comment: Is it possible to simply subtract two from the reference? I have been searching for a way to do that but haven't found anything